# File Manager with a command line panel

Tags: command-line, filemanager

At some point, years ago, I found a file manager that had a panel that you could enter command lines. I have search for Linux file managers but unable to locate it. Does anyone know what file manager it was?

Comment: You must refer to the nautilus terminal: http://www.techerator.com/2011/06/using-the-linux-command-line-with-nautilus-terminal/. I am afraid however, it is not available anymore, since all links are dead.

Comment: According to this: https://wetechgeeks.wordpress.com/2016/07/22/nautilus-terminal-extension-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/ it should work, but not on my system...

Comment: Thank you Jacob. I found the source files. I am going to try to update it to work with 16.04. If i do i will share it out

Comment: TonyD, were you able to get it working with 16.04?